# Grouping similar words (bad , worse )

Tags: text-processing, text-analysis

I know there are ways to find synonyms either by using NLTK/pywordnet or Pattern package in python but it isn't solving my problem.

If there are words like

- bad,worst,poor
- bag,baggage
- lost,lose,misplace

I am not able to capture them. Can anyone suggest me a possible way?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear.  Some of your words are (near) synonyms, others are related by other means.  *worse* is the comparative of *bad,* so baseform reduction would reveal this. Similarly, *lost* is the participle of *lose.* More bewilderingly, the relation between *bag* and *baggage* is etymological (if even there is one -- the dictionary I used simply said it's a French loan word, but "possibly related" to *bag)* which doesn't generalize very well; it would reveal obscure relationships like that between *surprise* and *seize.*

Comment: That's the problem actually. By reading we can differentiate between the different classes in which words exist, but how to make a computer do that. :)

Comment: That's definitely "too broad" then. Whole books are being written. Majoring in computational linguistics would be a good start.

Comment: I think it's too late for you to make a new answer helpful to you. However I'm writing one that may help someone later...

Answer (score 3):

There have been numerous research in this area in past 20 years. Yes computers don't understand language but we can train them to find similarity or difference in two words with the help of some manual effort.

Approaches may be:

1. Based on manually curated datasets that contain how words in a language are related to each other.
2. Based on statistical or probabilistic measures of words appearing in a corpus.

**Method 1:**

Try Wordnet. It is a human-curated network of words which preserves the relationship between words according to human understanding. In short, it is a graph with nodes as something called 'synsets' and edges as relations between them. So any two words which are very close to each other are close in meaning. Words that fall within the same synset might mean exactly the same. Bag and Baggage are close - which you can find either by iteratively exploring node-to-node in a breadth first style - like starting with 'baggage', exploring its neighbors in an attempt to find 'baggage'. You'll have to limit this search upto a small number of iterations for any practical application. Another style is starting a random walk from a node and trying to reach the other node within a number of tries and distance. It you reach baggage from bag say, 500 times out of 1000 within 10 moves, you can be pretty sure that they are very similar to each other. Random walk is more helpful in much larger and complex graphs.

[image]
There are many other similar resources online.

**Method 2:**

Word2Vec. Hard to explain it here but it works by creating a vector of a user's suggested number of dimensions based on its context in the text. There has been an idea for two decades that words in similar context mean the same. e.g. I'm gonna check out my bags and I'm gonna check out my baggage both might appear in text. You can read the paper for explanation (link in the end).

So you can train a Word2Vec model over a large amount of corpus. In the end, you will be able to get 'vector' for each word. You do not need to understand the significance of this vector. You can this vector representation to find similarity or difference between words, or generate synonyms of any word. The idea is that words which are similar to each other have vectors close to each other.

Word2vec came up two years ago and immediately became the 'thing-to-use' in most of NLP applications. The quality of this approach depends on amount and quality of your data. Generally Wikipedia dump is considered good training data for training as it contains articles about almost everything that makes sense. You can easily find ready-to-use models trained on Wikipedia online.

A tiny example from Radim's website:

```
>>> model.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'], topn=1)
[('queen', 0.50882536)]
>>> model.doesnt_match("breakfast cereal dinner lunch".split())
'cereal'
>>> model.similarity('woman', 'man')
0.73723527
```

First example tells you the closest word **(topn=1)** to words **woman** and **king** but meanwhile also most away from the word **man**. The answer is **queen**.. Second example is odd one out. Third one tells you how similar the two words are, in your corpus.

Easy to use tool for Word2vec :

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf (Warning : Lots of Maths Ahead)

Comment: At first I was ready to downvote you, because I didn't see any practical use to getting maths in this... But then I realised your solution is by far better than mine. Neat answer. (:

Comment: @A.Abramov I didn't find your answer on this question! Deleted?

Comment: Yeah. Yours is better (:

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However sharing ideas is how we grow - worst one can get here is a couple of downvotes.

Comment: @A.Abramov Ah I see. Well people working in the area of NLP would be well-aware of these solutions. OP should have used better tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aditya. I already am using wordnet as mentioned in question using pywordnet (python package). The problem is it does loose many synonyms in dataset.

Regarding word2vec, yes it's a very good approach but it has its limitation of training models( Especially when I want synonyms for different domains).
Thanks anyways for explaining it in such a good way!